# Django installed_apps does not recognise my app?

Tags: django

This is my installed apps section in settings.py.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig',
.
.
.
]
```

My app name is "homepage" and I really can't remember why I changed it to  'homepage.apps.HomepageConfig', but whatever it is, it worked on my machine.

Now, i uploaded my files to server, installed required apps, did the migrations, but i noticed django does not create my "homepage" app table and does not migrate anything from my app. And my website returns the error: table homepage_post does not exist.

What is wrong?

Comment: Does renaming your app, back to "homepage" do anything different?

Comment: Yes, i already did that, it says, import error, no module names homepage.apps.

Comment: If the problem is that your app tables do not exist, then the problem is with your migrations. How are you running them? Did you commit the result of running makemigrations locally? Where are you deploying to?

Answer (score 1):

Check if in `homepage` app directory You have file named `__init__.py` and `apps.py`. The content of `apps.py` should be:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class HomepageConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'homepage'
```

Comment: Yeah both of the files exist. And it has the same content as you said.

Comment: Versions of Django on your machine and server are the same?

Comment: Should they exactly be the same? On server it is the latest. On my machine it is two months old maximum.

Comment: If you have Django version under 1.7, homepage.apps.HomepageConfig won't wor

Comment: Both of them are greater than 1.6(i think both are over 1.10). Sorry i am using my phone now dont't have access to pc now. I currently have access to server just.