# Can't runserver on Django

Tags: python, django

I just started playing with Django, and I encountered a problem. Here's what it said when I tried to runserver.

ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf '' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Here's what I did.

On setting.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Siblog.apps.SiblogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',**strong text**
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Project urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Siblog.urls')),
]
```

Siblog urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='Siblog-home'),
]
```

Siblog views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'Siblog/home.html')
```

Also the template I've created inside of the Siblog file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
     <h1>Siblog Home!</h1>>
 </body>        
</html>
```

Comment: Please try solutions described in comments in the following issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047268/django-installed-apps-does-not-recognise-my-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon at quick glance you need to modify a few things.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'Siblog', ]
```

As long as you properly have the app set in the installed apps section the way you setup the rest of the project seems fine.

Comment: Now it's saying : ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: Siblog

Comment: Never mind it runs now. It's weird cause I technically didn't change anything.